# "Since" + Present Perfect

Tags: grammar

According to a grammar book (Advanced English Grammar in Use, Cambridge) we should use "since" as follows:

"We use the present perfect in the time clause with *since* if the two situations described in the main clause and the time clause extend until the present." 
E.g. Since I´ve been able to drive, I've felt much more independent.

I wonder, is it correct to use simple present instead of present perfect in that sense? I.e, "Since I am able to drive."

Comment: No. The example in your book unambiguously uses ***since*** with the sense of *a period of time extending up to the present*, but your version is extremely likely to be misinterpreted as having the sense ***since = because*** (i.e. - you'd probably be accused of writing a "garden path" sentence where the reader is forced to "backtrack" and adopt a different interpretation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both grammatically correct, but they have different meanings. [The relevant ones here are](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/since?s=t):

> 7.
>   continuously from or counting from the time when:
>   *He has been busy since he came*.
>
> 8.
>   because; inasmuch as:
>   *Since you're already here, you might as well stay*.

Your first example has meaning #7

> Since I´ve been able to drive, I've felt much more independent.

*From the time I started driving until now, I have felt more independent*.

But changing the tense changes the meaning to #8

> Since I am able to drive, I feel more independent.

*Because I can now drive, I feel more independent than I did before*.